# How to catch when the arrow down key is pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a flowlayoutPanel and I add 50 userControl to this flowlayoutPanel dynamically
I wire up the event keyUp for each UserControl so the event handler for keyup is triggered. So I start to click on a user control and let it have focus then
I click the button arrow down or arrow up so the wired up event handler  for keyup is called.

But there is a problem when I change direction for example when I have clicked arrow down for example 10 times and then click arrow up the event handler is called but the scroll bar is not moving until I have clicked 5 times on the arrow up.

So the first 4 click doesn't move the scroll bar at all.

I have also tried with this.KeyPreview = true; in the form c-tor
so the form get the keyup event but the problem is the same.

I home sombody can give me a solution to my problem.

//Tony

Comment: void ctrl_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In ctrl_KeyUp");
        }

Comment: I can't understand why the scrollbar is not moving when the event handler is called.

Comment: The cursor keys are used for navigation, like the Tab key.  So you have to press it 4 times to move the focus from, say, the bottom one to the top one that is visible.  Press it one more time to move the focus back, now the panel has to scroll to ensure that the control that has the focus is visible.  This behavior can be changed, you probably shouldn't.  You should instead fix your UserControl so that it is obvious that it has the focus.  Use ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle().  With additional high odds that this should not be a UserControl but a plain Control.